# Quadratic transformation of a variable

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to learn some machine learning and was wondering what is quadratic and cubic transformations of data and how is it done? One guy on the [forum](https://www.kaggle.com/c/prudential-life-insurance-assessment/forums/t/18143/scikit-learn-svc-and-linearsvc-to-fit-model/103478#post103478) is talking about it and I was wondering what is the transformation of a variable and how it is done.
Thank you

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it's just taking the element-wise square of the data

Comment: @toasted_flakes Not just element-wise. Quadratic terms also include interactions between them.

Comment: @DavidMaust I didn't know this practice had a name. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polynomial features (quadratic, cubic, etc.) are used to reduce bias in a model and allow for interactions between terms. In scikit-learn it is implemented as a transformation in [sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

The idea is if you have three features `a`,`b`, and `c`. The quadratic features would be generated by expanding `(a + b + c) ^ 2`. Thus `a^2`, `b^2` `c^2`, `a*b`, `a*c`, `b*c` would be the set of quadratic features.

Within scikit-learn's `PolynomialFeatures`, when the argument `degree` is passed, all terms up to that degree are created.

This is typically used prior to building a linear model. It allows for lower bias, but it very quickly increases the size of the feature set.

Comment: to be more precise the growth is exponential in the polynomial degree, thus kernel methods are preferable.